# How to bypass code signing in xcode 4.4 for iOS 5?

Tags: ios, xcode, ios5

How do I circumvent code signing in xcode 4.4 for iOS 5?

Trying to get a demo out the door for a presentation at a board meeting and don't have time to wait for it to clear the app store process. I will submit through regular channels later. This is a time issue, not a money issue. Any thoughts?

Found lots of demos for 4.2 and lower but nothing for 4.4.

Comment: App store approval is just needed before selling. If you want to load it on a device it can be done on your dev devices. Which are you trying to do?

Comment: I am trying to allow senior members in the company to download the demo app by way of a web link to view and test it before the app store submission. I was hoping to bypass the code signing as apposed to having them install xcode and view it by means of the simulator, or have to deal with public and privet keys, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Testflight](http://testflightapp.com) to distribute the application ad-hoc. Just sign it with a distribution provisioning profile and don't forget to include the Entitlements.plist ( with `Can be debugged` set to NO)

Answer (score 1):

Looking at your comment, have a look at [TestFlight](http://testflightapp.com/). You can have them easily install your app, and you can set it up in seconds.

Comment: CBrown : I use it a lot and it's really great :) @Andrei Stoleru got me by 25 seconds ! lol

Answer (score 1):

What you're looking for is Ad Hoc Distribution: you build your app with a profile containing the UDIDs of any devices it is permitted to run on, then users can install it via iTunes or directly over the web.

I highly recommend using a service like [TestFlight](http://testflightapp.com) to handle the distribution. It can also collect the device UDIDs for you, if users register via the site.

Unless an iOS device is jailbroken, it will refuse to run any app that has not been signed. If this were not the case, it would be trivial to completely bypass the App Store, something Apple doesn't want to allow. The Ad Hoc Distribution process allows you to distribute outside the app store, but only to a limited number of devices (100). Apple controls this since you must generate the provisioning profiles (basically the list of device UDIDs) via its website.

Comment: Very insightful. Thanks for the response.